# Resume spotify after playing own audio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, spotify

I am coding a WP7 & WP8 sports tracking app that gives the user feedback through voice coaching. If a user is playing music, it needs to be paused, the voice coach needs to speak and finally the music must be resumed again. For the standard music player, i based my coding on the information given on [this website](http://www.governor.co.uk/news-plus-views/2011/2/16/resuming-background-music-in-wp7-applications), and it works for the standard music player, but not for Spotify.

I've been looking into it and the mediaplayer seems to lose track of Spotify when i pause their music, and Spotify seems to crash. There is no music in the MediaPlayer.Queue when Spotify is playing so i can't save and restore that. It's also not possible to simply try a MediaPlayer.Resume(); after pausing Spotify because the music player does not know what to play anymore due to the empty playlist.

Is it possible to create a windows phone app that is compitable with Spotify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible as 3rd party media applications such as Spotify don't use the `MediaPlayer` and so `MediaPlayer.Resume()` won't work for them.

You could request Microsoft to implement this in a future version the OS via the [uservoice site](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions).